# Co-worker lies about the time he works

Tags: salary, unprofessional-behavior, work-time

I have sort of a moral dillema. I have an office job with two other people. One of them I am the supervisor of but do not 'sign their paycheck'. Instead, I simply make sure they have work to do and stay on track. It is expected of me that I make sure that projects get done, meaning I must make sure they come in when they say they will and are productive.

Note: This job allows employees to make their own hours. This means that employees are expected to come in when they say they will. The manager who would be my direct supervisor does not enforce this rule so it is taken advantage of. We will also enter in all of our own hours and they are approved by the manager. This allows for employees to be dishonest if they wish.

Enter the second employee. I have not officially been told that I am their supervisor, however, their initial job title has transformed into the job title of the employee that I do supervise. This is not official but everybody knows it (once again bad management). This employee has a set schedule (that they created) but does not follow it. They come in between 2 and 3 hours late everyday. Since they come in late they supposedly stay later (according to the time entries) but we dont know because we work a normal 9-5.

However, this employee does enter time as if they arrived 30 minutes to 1.5 hrs earlier very frequently. I can see it in an approved and processed state. They also leave for hour lunches but do not mention them in their time entry (no paid lunch).

This employee is logging approximately 3 hours in some cases more than they actually work per day and getting paid for it.

What should I do?

Comment: Are the project deadlines affected/left behind due to his hours?

Comment: There is no hard deadline yet for their project but it slows productivity severely.

Comment: how do you measure that if there are no deadlines? I mean is there a specific way to demonstrate that his lack of presence causes something damaging to the team/company?

Comment: Are you salaried our hourly workers?

Comment: At first, simply ask clearly "Am I officially the supervisor of X?"

Comment: Are they getting their work done? If they are not, then that is the real problem. If they *are* getting their work done, then either assign more work or accept that they are a highly productive employee who produces such amazing results so quickly that they don't even need the entire business day.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: the planning of work is based on standard hours. He should said that he can finish faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Communicate with your superior.

From what you're saying, it sounds like your responsibility is essentially to get the job done at the price and in the time that your superior expects.  From what I'm reading, at any rate, it sounds like you're basically a facilitator between the superior and the subordinates to, as you said, keep them "on track."

When something like this comes up, your superior has to know about it.  He is the one whose pocket is going to be hit: essentially, it sounds like you are there to keep this kind of thing from happening.

When you talk to him, you should clarify at least two things:

#### 1. Is this person your subordinate?

You mentioned that it wasn't official that you are really responsible for this person.  If you aren't, this issue isn't in your department, and you can just alert your superior of it and pass on to other things.  Whatever the case, there should be an official position on it.  Request that it be made official if at all possible.

#### 2. What should be done in this situation?

Mention that this is an issue, and ask him / her what (s)he recommends you do in this situation.  Should you work out a different way to work hours?  Should you send an official warning that this behaviour is not acceptable?  Should you leave it totally in the hands of your superior?

---

Hope some of this helps!

Comment: How is the "job done in the time expected" related to communicate to the supervisor about the working hours? What if the job is finished regardless of the hours the poster reported?

Comment: @smith Management still needs to know. With this IF there are 3 options for management: 1. they have a dishonest employee who gets fired, 2. they have an employee who is more efficient than expected but wants to work shorter hours, so you make official what he's been doing, 3. you have someone more efficient than expected, so you give them more (ambitious) tasks. In any case management needs to know and deal with the situation.

Answer (score 3):

If the person who is abusing from the situation is a subordinate of yours, you should give him/her a couple of informal warnings (first could be verbal and 2nd and third ideally in writing so that you would have evidence to sustain your claims with superiors), and if he/she continues to abuse from the situation, advise your superiors regarding the situation (also ideally in writing.
If a project starts to fail or fall behind schedules (because of this person) notify your superiors...
After all you should not take the fall and/or blame for the abuse of others.